# Does Azure B2C provide REST API for login?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, db2-content-manager

I have one application integrated with Azure B2C directory. Our problem is, login page is redirecting to Azure B2C portal (Own custom page) for authenticate or Authorize users and then revert back to the original website.

I need to open popup with my own website login design and at the backend, I am able to call Azure B2C REST api to validate users.

How I can create REST API for Login in Azure B2C portal?

Let me know if you have any information about the same.

Comment: You are looking for the ROPC flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: I think Applications (Legacy) is deprecated. Please let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: Yeah it is. The documentation link I posted has the examples for the newer App registrations experience too. "To register an application in your Azure AD B2C tenant, you can use our new unified App registrations experience or our legacy Applications (Legacy) experience."

Comment: Hi @KetanGarala, have you found solution for this, I was also researching for similar condition and also give user to access with Google/Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

As juunas said in the comment, you could use resource owner password credentials(ROPC) [flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) to validate users at the backend. You could call the API with the POST request at the end. **Note:** ROPC supports local accounts only.

Try to create resource owner user flow first.

[image]

You need to replace the `username` and `password` with the user's to be verified.

```
POST https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_<ROPC_Auth name of the flow>/oauth2/v2.0/token

username=<username>
&password=<password>
&grant_type=password
&scope=openid <application-id> offline_access
&client_id=<application-id>
&response_type=token+id_token
```

Comment: Thanks Pamela,Can you please share a document for "ROPC supports local accounts only" this?

The client has 1500K customers in Azure B2C portal. should I use ROPC REST API to validate it?

Comment: Which Support Account Type should i select at the time of app creation?

Accounts in this organizational directory only (Addact Technologies Pvt Ltd only - Single tenant)
* Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)
* Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and  personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)
*Personal Microsoft accounts only

Comment: I am not able to see user flow types. Why? there is just name and identity provider by default selected and user parameters.

Comment: The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) shows that "ROPC supports local accounts only": https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEQK7.png

Comment: Thank you @Pamela Peng. I will look into this.